# Following reinstall of failed hard drive, RMarkdown graphics now vary in size

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

My Mac's hard drive failed and I had a replacement drive installed.  All R related programs were installed as if my computer was brand new.

Prior to the failure, if I inserted a graphic into a RMardown document, the rendered size of the graphic was consistent and directly related to the actual  size of the screen shot image.

Now, relatively small screen captures render large in size.  I attempt to add a pic to show the problem.  Not certain what I need to do to fix this situation.  This is a book that will soon go to publication.  As is stands, the publication is delayed unless I am able to somehow return to 'normal.'  A Time Machine restore is out of the question for reasons I cannot go into, even though that was attempted.  Several Apple senior advisors with whom I spoke do not recommend the 'Time Machine' restore option.  As such, I seek another solution - hopefully not individually resizing 1,200+ text images. [pic of mis-sizing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t9pr8ljnm915ow/stack_overflow_q1.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Not an answer, but do you think you could make a minimal version of your book with just that one page? If the issue shows up in that, then it might be easier for someone to spot the issue (I think it might simply too hard to do so from your description).

Comment: I'd guess that a simple `.Rmd` file + the 6 images would suffice.